# get value by column index where row is a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe sheet_overview:

```
    Unnamed: 0 Headline Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3
  0         nan    1. 1.   username       Erik
  1         nan    1. 2.    userage         23
  2         nan    1. 3.   favorite        ice
```

I want to get the value **23**, by looking for "**1. 2.**" in the second column.
If I don't want to go onto the column names, I have to use the index. My question is, if my approach is too complicated.

It works but it seems to be too much and not very pythonic:

```
age = sheet_overview.iloc[
                    sheet_overview[
                        sheet_overview.iloc[:, 1] == '1. 2.']
                        .index[0], 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for numpy array for filter with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then use `next` for return first matched value - if not exist get `missing`:

```
a = sheet_overview.iloc[(sheet_overview.iloc[:, 1] == '1. 2.').values, 3]

a = next(iter(a), 'missing')
print (a)
23
```

If performance is important , use `numba`:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def first_val(A, k):
    a = A[:, 0]
    b = A[:, 1]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == k:
            return b[i]
    return 'missing'

a = first_val(sheet_overview.iloc[:, [1,3]].values, '1. 2.')
```

Comment: It's nice to already have an error compensation, but are there other benefits, like saving memory or time?

Comment: @ErikSteiner - it depends of data and also of position of matched data in column.